# Is my Amazon S3 client synchronous or async?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Here is my code

```
    import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
    import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client;
    
    public class AwsS3Helper
    {
        private AmazonS3 s3Client;
    
        public AwsS3Helper()
        {
            try
            {
                AWSCredentials credentials = new PropertiesCredentials ....
    
                s3Client = new AmazonS3Client( credentials );

                s3Client.putObject(putObjectRequest);
```

What I would like to know is,  is this an asynchronous or synchronous operation?  I use DynamoDB and it has 2 different clients,  an async and sync one,  but I don't see any other S3Client in the Amazon SDK

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This statement, from the documentation is pointing to a synchronous operation. Moreover it doesnt take any parameter for async indication of the result.

"Amazon S3 never stores partial objects; if during this call an exception wasn't thrown, the entire object was stored."
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html#putObject(com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest)

Answer (score 3):

as answered it is not Async, although the Sdk has Async clients for other services.
this is also confirmed here (https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/140)

**but** also note that in the new version of the sdk (2.0) you have Async client for s3
(https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2).

Answer (score -1):

I think TransferUtility is what you want:

https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx2KF0YUQITA164/AWS-SDK-for-Android-Transfer-Manager-to-Transfer-Utility-Migration-Guide